# Microsoft Desktop Search - CONTAINS not returning results on windows server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, wds

I am trying to search a remote fileshare (running windows server 2008 R2)
for files that contain some text. If I try this, it works fine:

```
SELECT System.FileName
FROM RemoteServer.SystemIndex 
WHERE SCOPE='file://RemoteServer/FileShare'
```

and I get lots of results. But as soon as I try to search for some text I get no results:

```
SELECT System.FileName
FROM RemoteServer.SystemIndex 
WHERE SCOPE='file://RemoteServer/FileShare'
AND CONTAINS('a')
```

if I try it on my machine (Windows 7) it works fine:

```
SELECT FileName
FROM SystemIndex 
WHERE CONTAINS('a')
```

Here is my c# code that I'm using to search:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"";
using (OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection  = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    myOleDbConnection.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand  = new OleDbCommand(sql, myOleDbConnection))
    {
        using (myDataReader = myOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!myDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Query returned 0 rows!");
            }
            else
            {
                // Process results here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

- Rebuilt the index
- Checked that the folder "FileShare" has been added on the server to be indexed
- Checked the "File Types" tab, that the correct extensions are ticked, and that "Index Properties and File Contents" is selected for those extensions
- Restarted the indexing service
- Restarted the server itself

to no avail.

Any other suggestions? Frustrating as I'm 99% of the way there. This whole windows desktop search seems to be pretty unsupported, maybe I should bin it and use something else?

Comment: Have you run the query locally on the server to see if it is returning results?  Are you looking for a string without spaces or single character, or are you looking for a sentence or phrase?  The CONTAINS predicate with no column defined searches ONLY the contents of the file as well, not sure if you had intended that.

Comment: Also you may try reordering your WHERE clause to move CONTAINS first and SCOPE second to see if that matters any...

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring a nvarchar variable for the search word

> DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(30) = 'a'

Then Modify your code to:

> SELECT FileName
>
> FROM SystemIndex
>
> WHERE CONTAINS(@SearchWord)

This excerpt is from TechNet on CONTAINS [See TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

*contains_search_condition* is nvarchar. An implicit conversion occurs
 when another character data type is used as input. In the following
 example, the @SearchWord variable, which is defined as varchar(30),
 causes an implicit conversion in the CONTAINS predicate.

Comment: It doesn't work.
Search.CollatorDSO.1” provider don't support ICommandWithParameters interface.Current provider program don't support command parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. After serval days suffering trying, I found out this code that can run in windows server 2008 r2:

```
AND CONTAINS('keyword')
->
and System.Search.AutoSummary like '%keyword%'
```