# Windows Desktop Search not returning QueryFocusedSummary

Tags: c#, wds

When searching through files indexed using Windows Desktop Search,
it would be nice if I could see a snippet of the text within the 
document that is related to the search text. However when I try to 
retrieve "System.Search.QueryFocusedSummary" or 
"System.Search.QueryFocusedSummaryWithFallback " I get a 
"column name not found" error.

(The code that I am using to query this is shown in this question: 
[Microsoft Desktop Search - CONTAINS not returning results on windows server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827546/microsoft-desktop-search-contains-not-returning-results-on-windows-server-2008) )

This is confusing because when you do a search within explorer,
you get the snippet of text in your results. So it's possible somehow.

According to this documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
it should be retrievable, the same that AutoSummary is.

This question has already been asked on MSDN here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdesktopsearchdevelopment/thread/dcfb40ea-b250-4294-80d0-727c7365745e/

but I'm hoping that the clever stackoverflow people can help me.

As a side note, I'm quite confused as to why this doesn't work, don't lots of
people need to index and search documents? Does everyone use Lucene and/or Solr
or Windows Search Server instead?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine ran into this problem recently. QueryFocusedSummary and QueryFocusedSummaryWithFallback are indeed not accessible via OLEDB. They are, however, accessible via Shell.

In the Windows SDK, there is a sample, `$WIN_SDK/Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/ExplorerBrowserSearch`, which will get you set up on using Shell functions to perform a search. From here, it should be trivial to add support for QueryFocusedSummary and QueryFocusedSummaryWithFallback via the Shell Property Keys `PKEY_Search_QueryFocusedSummary` and `PKEY_Search_QueryFocusedSummaryWithFallback` respectively.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in my C# application, and the C++ sample code is hard for me to follow.  Can you be more specific about what needs to be done to get the `QueryFocusedSummary`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any code I have to speculate a bit...

I assume you are using OleDB/SQL to execute a query...

Neither `QueryFocusedSummary` nor `QueryFocusedSummaryWithFallback` are real columns and thus NOT available via OleDB/SQL !

The only columns available this way are AFAIK

```
AutoSummary 
Contents 
EntryID 
GatherTime 
Rank 
Store
```

`QueryFocusedSummary` and `QueryFocusedSummaryWithFallback` are IIRC properties accessiable via [COM or a Shell interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb331575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#consuming_windows_search_results) .

Comment: Thanks for your help - There is a link to the code that I am using in the question. Also according to the msdn documentation that I linked to I don't see how autosummary is any different to QueryFocusedSummary. What is an IIRC property?

Comment: @LachlanB IIRC = "If I Remember Correctly"... property is a COM term, whil AutoSummary is Column (accessible via SQL) QueryFocusedSummary is only accessible via COM. check the link I provided, there is a lot of reading material...

Comment: @LachlanB The code you link to is using CONTAINS - I might be overlooking something but there is no mention of QueryFocusedSummary in the link... at least it confirms my thinking that you are using SQL...